# How to run an Android app in IntelliJ Simulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ 12 and Android SDK 10 and 17. I setup a simple "hello world" android app in IntelliJ. Then I run the app in emulator using IntelliJ. IntelliJ executes the following command:

```
"D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd AVD_for_Nexus_S_by_Google -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

Android emulator runs but the "hello world" app is not inside it:

[image]

What should I do in order to make the emulator execute "hello world" app? I guess there should be some reference to the app in the above command.

Comment: this link may hekp you http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Simple_Android_application_from_scratch_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_11.0

Comment: Check what the "Run"-tap (by default at the bottom left) says. It gives information about the deployment process.

Comment: That just starts the emulator.  In Build->Edit configurations, make sure you have the chooser dialog selected then run your app.  Select the emulator as the target.